# Magento 2.2.3. Your current session has been expired. How to fix it.

Tags: session, magento2

I hope this will help someone. I spent a lot of time trying to figure out what is going on.

I updated the php.ini sessions settings, added a row to the core_config_table with session 86400 and it was not helping.

**The Solution that worked for me is:**

Go to the database into the admin_session table and update the column type updated_at from a TIMESTAMP to CURRENT TIMESTAMP in dropdown.

Thank you,
Cons
[Magento 2 Session issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRh63.jpg)

Comment: ALTER TABLE `admin_user_session` CHANGE `created_at` `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Created Time', CHANGE `updated_at` `updated_at` TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Update Time';

Comment: Does not work, there is no "CURRENT TIMESTAMP" in the dropdown...